# SQL Server 2008 R2 VB.net Connection

Tags: database, vb.net, database-connection, sql-server-2008-r2

Hey all I am trying to connect to my SQL Server that I log into using my windows authentication user name and password. However, when I use that information in the code below it tells me that it can not connect...

```
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim cnn As SqlConnection
    connetionString = "Data Source=MSSQLPROD;Initial Catalog=MS435_PROD;User ID=me.here;Password=mypassword;"
    cnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

    Try
        cnn.Open()
        MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
        cnn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
    End Try
```

Comment: Very helpful for any questions relating to connection strings: [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using SQL Server authentication when you specify a user name and password in the connection string.  Remove the user name and password and include:

```
Data Source=MSSQLPROD;Initial Catalog=MS435_PROD;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

That will cause the connection to use the Windows authentication of the context executing the code.